# WYSING editor not working

Tags: magento2, extensions, uicomponent

WYSING editior isnot working in magento 2 admin

Answer (score 2):

Try to move all arguments of the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory` in one node, like:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="junosync_product_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Junorocket\Junosync\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Grid\Collection</item>
            <item name="junosync_category_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Junorocket\Junosync\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Thankd it is working now

Comment: @DeveloperWebile I'm glad to help you. Please, accept my answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file 
    vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php
Find this function

```
    protected function _getMatchedNode($nodePath)
{
    $xPath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
    if ($this->rootNamespace) {
        $xPath->registerNamespace(self::ROOT_NAMESPACE_PREFIX, $this->rootNamespace);
    }
    $matchedNodes = $xPath->query($nodePath);
    $node = null;
    if ($matchedNodes->length > 1) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase("More than one node matching the query: %1", [$nodePath])
        );
    } elseif ($matchedNodes->length == 1) {
        $node = $matchedNodes->item(0);
    }
    return $node;
}
```

and before the exception just log the node path. like echo $nodePath die; Actually recent lines in  stack trace in exption.log will tell you the node that is problematic. Could you post stack trace

Comment: i have check and echo  $nodePath and get  /config/type[@name='Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory']

above node are config please provide me solution

Comment: Answer provided by @siarhey is correct